# get_the_excerpt() removes all p tags in page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have written some shortcode to be able to place the latest post excerpt anywhere on the page, but I got a problem that I have trying to solve for days now! And I can't find the reason why the `get_the_excerpt()` removes all p tags around text in other parts of the page. When I remove `get_the_excerpt()` from the code, it's no problem with the other text inside other shortcodes, but when I put i back, the problem is back! Please have a look at the code and tell me what I have done wrong or could improve! Thanks!

```
<?php

function show_posts() { 
    global $post;

    $html = "";
    $extra_css = "";
    $latestPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=1');

    if($latestPosts->have_posts()): 
        while($latestPosts->have_posts()): $latestPosts->the_post();

        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {     
            $extra_css = "has-thumbnail";
        }

        $html = "<div class='wide'><article class='post {$extra_css}'>";
        $html .= "<div class='post-thumbnail'>";
        $html .= "<a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_post_thumbnail(null,'thumbnail') . "</a>";  
        $html .= "<div class='post-thumbnail-date'><h4>" . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . " </h4></div>";
        $html .= "</div><!-- end post-thumbnail -->";
        $html .= "<h3><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></h3>";
        $html .= "<p class='post-info'>" . get_the_time('Y-m-d') . " | Av " . get_the_author() . "</p>";
        $html .= "<p class='post-text'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p><p><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'> Läs mer...</a></p>"; 
        $html .= "</article></div>";

        endwhile;
    else:
        // Error message
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('blogg','show_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_excerpt()` is removing `<p>` tags elsewhere because you are using `wpautop`, and are nesting `get_the_excerpt()` within a paragraph. This means that you're ending up with nested `<p>` tags, which is invalid HTML, and is causing the parser to get confused.

Instead, you should nest `get_the_excerpt()` within a `<div>` (or other block-level element):

```
$html .= "<div class='post-text'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</div><p><a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'> Läs mer...</a></p>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help! I copy/paste your line of code and I thougt the problem would finally be solved, but no :( Any other ideas? Are my p tag really nested!? To me it looks like they start and ends after each other?